# How to change object structure

Tags: javascript, object

I want to change the structure of my JavaScript object to another. My problem is that for each object, I have to create up to three different objects:

My input:

```
[
  {date: "21-05", cash: "500", card: "200", points: "100"},
  {date: "26-05", card: "100", points: "50"}
]
```

Desired output:

```
[
  {date: "21-05", amount: "500", paymentType: cash }, 
  {date: "21-05", amount: "200", paymentType: card }, 
  {date: "21-05", amount: "200", paymentType: points }, 
  {date: "26-05", amount: "100", paymentType: card }, 
  {date: "26-05", amount: "50",  paymentType: points }
]
```

*cash, card, point* are global `const`

Comment: What have you tried? Loop over it and push three new objects to an array.

Comment: Both those examples are invalid JSON.

Comment: `date:"21-05",` is not JSON. In JSON a key has to wrapped into double quotes. The objects you show are JavaScript Objects. JSON in JavaScript a stringified representation of data, so JSON data is always of the type string.

Comment: While I agree the wording is wrong, this is clearly object manipulation, not JSON manipulation, you don't need to be a pedant @Quentin

Comment: @PatrickRoberts The title says JSON, the question says JSON (three times), the tags say `json`. It's not JSON. This is a pretty fundamental issue, not pedantry.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts the mixing of those two terms will sooner or later result in other problems. If the OP e.g. search for how to handle JSON objects the OP might find answers that say, that `JSON.parse(jsonObj)` is need to access JSON objects, but calling `JSON.parse` on a JavaScript object would for sure not work, so it is important to give the OP this information. Downvoting because of that is on the other hand not necessary.

Comment: Im new in this. sorry please , I'll be better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could iterate the array and the keys and check if not `date`, then build a new object with the data. Collect until all objects are visited.

```js
var data = [{ date: "21-05", cash: "500", card: "200", points: "100" }, { date: "26-05", card: "100", points: "50" }],
    result = data.reduce(function (r, o) {
        Object.keys(o).forEach(function (k) {
            if (k !== 'date') {
                r.push({ date: o.date, amount: o[k], paymentType: k });
            }
        });
        return r;
    }, []);
    
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a couple of `for` loops for that:

```js
const data = [
    {date:"21-05", cash: "500", card:"200", points:"100"},
    {date: "26-05", card:"100", points:"50"}
];

const result = [];
for (let row of data) {
    for (let key in row) {
        if (key !== 'date') {
            result.push({
                data: row.date,
                amount: row[key],
                paymentType: key
            });
        }
    }
}

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```